# Why does my iOS build behave differently after closing and restarting the app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

We have a hybrid app that is a mix of Objective C and Swift that is showing some strange behavior in classes that haven't been touched in a long time.  If we do a fresh build from Xcode the app works fine, but if we close the app and restart it, it behaves totally different.  We re-attach the debugger and have seen viewWillAppear called but viewDidAppear is not called after re-opening.  Other things like NotificationCenter Observers don't fire after closing and re-opening either.  We've tried to track this down and I wish there was code that I could share that would point in the right direction, but it's a general thing in the app that is happening across most classes.  When building for test flight it behaves the way that misses the viewDidAppeaer and the observers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it swift calling Objective-C or Objective-C calling swift ?

Comment: @PtitXav it happens in both the Objective-C and Swift classes, and doesn't seem to have a pattern on which calls which.  One thing I'm going to look into is seeing if there are duplicate controllers being created.  We've slowly translated classes from Objective-C to Swift and think this may be the source of some of the issues.